# Python ElementTree - Inserting a copy of an element

Tags: python, xml

I have the following xml code:

```
<data factor="1" name="ini" value="342" />
```

I want to copy the same information, but with a different name. i.e., The final output should be:

```
<data factor="1" name="ini" value="342" />
<data factor="1" name="raw_ini" value="342" />
```

I tried to do the following:

```py
model_tag = tree.findall(data_path) #I make sure that data_path is correct.
len_tags = len(model_tag)
i = 0
while i < len_tags: 
    tipo_tag = model_tag[i]
    if tipo_tag.attrib['name']=='ini':
        aux_tag = copy.deepcopy(tipo_tag) #I tried also with copy.copy(tipo_tag).
        aux_tag.attrib['name'] = 'raw_ini'
        model_tag.append(aux_tag)

tree.write(dir_output)
```

If I use "copy.deepcopy" I don't have an extra element. The output is:

```
<data factor="1" name="ini" value="342" />
```

If I use "copy.copy", just change the name of the element. The output is:

```
<data factor="1" name="raw_ini" value="342" />
```

Any Idea of what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get the parent of those `data` elements and use the `Element.insert(index, element)` method.

Also, you need to use `deepcopy` and not just `copy`. The difference is that `deepcopy` creates a second object, whereas by using `copy` (which return a **shallow** copy of the object) you would just be modifying the first element (as you also figured out).

Let's say that you have `dataParent` as the parent of the `data` elements.

```
listData = dataParent.findall('data')
lenData = len(listData)
i = 0
while i < lenData:
    if listData[i].attrib['name'] == 'ini':
        copyElem = copy.deepcopy(dataElem)
        copyElem['name'] = 'raw_ini'
        dataParent.insert([index you wish], copyElem)
    i += 1
```

Comment: Sorry, but How can I get the parent? (I'm new working with xml)

Answer (score 1):

Where did the "copy" and "dataElem" come from in the above example? 
i.e. copyElem = **copy**.deepcopy(**dataElem**)

Answer (score 0):

For future reference.

Simplest way to copy a node (or tree) and keep it's children, without having to import **ANOTHER** library *ONLY* for that:

import xml.etree.ElementTree;

```
def copy_tree( tree_root ):
    return et.ElementTree( tree_root );

duplicated_node_tree = copy_tree ( node );    # type(duplicated_node_tree) is ElementTree
duplicated_tree_root_element = new_tree.getroot();  # type(duplicated_tree_root_element) is Element
```